# Use Varnish cache for one domain and not other domain on same server

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I got varnish installed on my server and made following changes for varnish cache to work.

Changes in `httpd.conf` :

- `Listen` changed from 80 => 8080
- `NameVirtualHost` from *80 => *8080

The content of httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/XYZ/
       ServerName  demo.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

IN `/etc/sysconfig/varnish` have made this change : `VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=80`

IN `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`: following change is done

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

For demo.example.com the varnish works fine.

But I also have **example.com, example.net and example.org** hosted on same server, which I would like to access without varnish involvement. As I changed the PORT from 80 => 8080 in `httpd.conf`, these sites won't work. Any way out what can be done?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for 'bypass varnish for a domain' turns up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728066/varnish-cache-only-specific-domain) post.

Sounds like exactly what you're looking for.